# How to convert decorator syntax to ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, ecmascript-next, react-dnd

I am trying to understand [some code](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple/Card.js) React written in ESnext (decorators).
I know how to convert decorators from ESnext to ES6 syntax

```
// ESnext
function collect(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  }
}

@DragSource(Types.CARD, cardSource, collect)
export default class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    const { isDragging, connectDragSource } = this.props;

    return connectDragSource(
      <div>
        I am a draggable card number {id}
        {isDragging && ' (and I am being dragged now)'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ES6

```
// ES6
function collect(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  };
}

class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    const { isDragging, connectDragSource } = this.props;

    return connectDragSource(
      <div>
        I am a draggable card number {id}
        {isDragging && ' (and I am being dragged now)'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DragSource(Types.CARD, cardSource, collect)(Card);
```

But I'm stuck how to convert this code to ES6 ?

```
function collectDrop(connect) {
  return {
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  };
}

function collectDrag(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  };
}

@DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, collectDrop)
@DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, collectDrag)
export default class Card extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    connectDropTarget: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    isDragging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    id: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    moveCard: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const { text, isDragging, connectDragSource, connectDropTarget } = this.props;
    const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1;

    return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(
      <div style={{ ...style, opacity }}>
        {text}
      </div>,
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: What you posted is not ES7. ES7 (ES2016) doesn't support decorators.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have two Higher Order Component (HOC) decorators you need to combine them and wrap your class when exporting with these two (DropTarget and DragSource). If you're using `redux` library then you can use its utility function `compose` that combines multiple HOCs and wraps the class with it. The code you need to focus on is at the end of the code below:

```
import { compose } from 'redux'

function collectDrop(connect) {
  return {
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  };
}

function collectDrag(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  };
}

class Card extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    connectDropTarget: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    isDragging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    id: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    moveCard: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const { text, isDragging, connectDragSource, connectDropTarget } = this.props;
    const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1;

    return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(
      <div style={{ ...style, opacity }}>
        {text}
      </div>,
    ));
  }
}

const enhance = compose(
  DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, collectDrop),
  DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, collectDrag)
)

export default enhance(Card)
```

Or (if you're not using redux) you can combine them like that:

```
// Comment this part out
/* const enhance = compose(
  DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, collectDrop),
  DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, collectDrag)
)

export default enhance(Card)*/

// and change to this

const dropTargetHOC = DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, collectDrop)
const dragSourceHOC = DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, collectDrag)

export default dropTargetHOC(dragSourceHOC(Card))
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript documentation provides good explanation of [decorator composition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition) (TS decorators and [ES decorators proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/) are identical for the most part):

> When multiple decorators apply to a single declaration, their
>   evaluation is similar to function composition in mathematics. In this
>   model, when composing functions f and g, the resulting composite (f ∘
>   g)(x) is equivalent to f(g(x)).
>
> As such, the following steps are performed when evaluating multiple
>   decorators on a single declaration in TypeScript:
>
> The expressions for each decorator are evaluated top-to-bottom.
>
> The results are then called as functions from bottom-to-top.

So it is supposed to be:

```
export default DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, collectDrop)(
  DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, collectDrag)(Card);
);
```

This is supposed to be used for academical purposes and not in production. The original code is not ES6 but JSX, it still requires a transpiler (Babel) to be converted to valid JavaScript. So there's no reason to not use all features that Babel can offer, including decorators.

Comment: Thanks! , the explanation is what I needed!